# Angular/ Typescript? /Javascript? - what does the ".default" mean?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Can someone explain what the ".default" means in the following code

I want to use such code in our project, but I am unsure about the code-fragment in question.

(I've altered my question to show the original code.)

In the article angular-http-mock-interceptor-for-mocked-backend-1h5g at dev.io one can read code like this:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import * as users from './users.json';

const urls = [
    {
        url: 'https://an-example.url.org/users',
        json: users
    }
];

@Injectable()
export class HttpMockRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        for (const element of urls) {
            if (request.url === element.url) {
                return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: ((element.json) as any).default })); // <---- THIS ".default"
            }
        }
    //...
    }
}
```

with users.json

```
[
 {
   "name": "Abe",
   "id": 1
 },
 {
   "name": "Boe",
   "id": 22
 }
]
```

I tried to google it, but with no success. I am not sure wether to try ot the code without the ".default" is sufficient enough, maybe I am missing something. That's why I would appreciate it to get some knowledge about the meaning.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `HttpResponse`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes, I did, but I've found no clue of it.

Comment: For whatever reason it's just trying to access the `default` property of the `false`. Since boolean does not have a default property, they casted it to `any` instead. 

I'm pretty sure somewhere in the code they overwritten the Boolean constructor or something similar

Comment: I've updated my question. The original code do not use a boolean literal.

Comment: is this angular? if so perhaps it provides some clues

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you, I've updated the head line and the tags.

Comment: it looks like its a property of `urls.json` what ever is in there.

Comment: I am confused about the order. It is first "cast" to any, and then the default-property is accessed. I don't understand why.

Comment: I hope my answer helped you. @EternalBeginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the default is because of the star import in here

```
import * as users from './users.json';
```

You could make that import

```
import users from './users.json';
```

You will notice that changing the import breaks the code,
so you need to remove that default. and change that line to

```
return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: element.json }));
```

[image: console.log the const urls]

Last thing is the reason you had to cast it is because json.element doesn't have that default property.

The previous image is just a console.log of the const urls.

The stackblitz URL.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mock-http-interceptor?file=src%2Fapp%2Finterceptor.mock.ts

```
I am confused about the order. It is first "cast" to any, and then the default-property is accessed. I don't understand why
```

A more natural way that you might think about is to assign the url type to any and that does work.

```
const urls:any = [
    {
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
        json: users
    }
];

@Injectable()
export class HttpMockRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        for (const element of urls) {
            if (request.url === element.url) {
                console.log('Loaded from json : ' + request.url);
                return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 200, body: element.json.default }));
            }
        }
        console.log('Loaded from http call :' + request.url);
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I would never have found this in a million years. Thank you so much :) I will include the imports in the question.

Comment: I am happy that it helped you.